# Apache Proxypass gives too many redirects error for https to http redirects

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, https, proxypass

I have an Apache 2.4 instance that has ProxyPass configured to point all incoming request with /abc

```
ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

RewriteEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia On

#### Generic Proxying of /web urls ####
ProxyPassMatch ^/abc/(.*)  http://142.100.5.163/abc/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/abc/(.*)  http://142.100.5.163/abc/$1
```

This works fine when I make a call from to the apache instance where the proxypass is configured. However, when I try to hit the instance via load balancer that is configured with an https domain (with SSL terminating at load balancer). Like https://www.an-app.com then I keep on getting a redirection error

That is

https://www.an-app.com/abc/page1.html -> too many redirects error
http://my-apache-instance/abc/page1.html -> shows the page1.html

If I trace the request it goes in an endless 301 redirect loop. Can someone please help me figure what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question! Have the same problem: infinite redirects when trying to access Splunk search headers which is accessible by http:// - from Apache https VirtualHost with cofigured mod_proxy_balancer.